# MVC pass parameter with form action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, forms, parameters

I got this code in my view that is used for a drag and drop function:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="~/Home/SaveUploadedFile" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" 
    id="dropzoneForm">
</form>
```

When an image gets dropped in the div the `SaveUploadedFile` gets triggered. The model im using in the view contains a `@Model.Name`that I would love to pass along to the method.

Can I somehow accomplish this in the above code or is it more complicated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a hidden input.

```
<form action="~/Home/SaveUploadedFile" method="post" 
    enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone" 
    id="dropzoneForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="@Model.Name" />
    <input id="btn_drop" type="button" value="Drop"/>
    ...
</form>
```

Then in jQuery

```
$('#btn_drop').on('click', function(){
     $('#dropzoneForm').submit();
});
```

Comment: Alright, thank you for answering! This gives me a new problem =) The way the form-action works now, the method gets triggered immediatly when an image in dropped in the div..If I do it like you are suggesting I need to modify the action so that it does not trigger the event until the button is pushed...any tips on that one?

Comment: Your code works without the button!
Just added this: <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
And it passes "test" to the controller. Thank you!